# Has there ever been an MLB game where the only hit was an inside-the-park home run?

Tags: baseball, trivia, mlb

Has there ever been a one-hitter MLB game in which the hit is an inside-the-park home run?

Comment: Doing some research here. Might be a problem as I'm not sure inside-the-park numbers are kept officially

Comment: Fun fact there have been 92 instances of a homerun being the only hit by a team in a game.

Comment: [This site](http://www.baseball-almanac.com/recbooks/rb_isphr.shtml) has a lot of information regarding all sorts of stuff relating to Inside The Park Home Runs (ITPHR). Don't see anything that would answer your question, but perhaps you can find some interesting things here. Field dimension changes must have been drastic over time as most players here who have recorded many ITPHR's are from early days of baseball.

Answer (score 4):

> Norichika Aoki's first Major League home run broke up a perfect game.
>
> Aoki's homer traveled only 213 feet in the air, a line drive that skipped past Rockies left fielder Carlos Gonzalez and rolled all the way to the fence in the fourth inning on Friday night at Miller Park.

[Source](http://milwaukee.brewers.mlb.com/news/print.jsp?ymd=20120420&content_id=29234486&vkey=news_mil&c_id=mil)

There ended up being a few more hits but that was the first that came in the fourth inning that day. That's the closest to what you are asking that I have heard of.